# magento 2: get review summary in homepage

Tags: magento2, review

I have call new product block using  widget grid in cms homepage. All data are available except review summary. How to display review summary details in product list in homepage.
Below function not working.

```
  echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml();
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this as you wish

```
<?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product,"sort",true); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The review summary is not included in the product widget. I think you can use  echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType, true) to display it.

Comment: You need to consider all paramiter value too